# How to remove empty error div from DOM in formik form?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have the following code in the authentication page to control alert messages:

```
<div className="messages-wrapper">
  {formik.errors.email &&
    <div className="alert alert-danger">
      <ErrorMessage name="email" />
    </div>
  }
  {formik.errors.password &&
    <div className="alert alert-danger">
      <ErrorMessage name="password" />
    </div>
  }
  {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
</div>
```

I realize that sometimes in DOM it has:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger"></div>
```

As a consequence, there is a **pink bar in the display**.

Does anyone know how to implement such that we only display an alert bar when it has text?

[image]

Comment: Empty string returns false. So,your code seems to work as your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code sample you've provided is not enough to give you a definitive answer.

But from what I see I can figure this much:

1. As per documentation [1](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/errormessage#example) and [2](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/errormessage#component) and the [source code](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/packages/formik/src/ErrorMessage.tsx) the `<ErrorMessage name="email">` will returns a string, and you code is roughly equivalent to

   ```js
   {formik.errors.email && <div className="alert alert-danger">
     {formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email ? formik.errors.email : null}
   </div>}
   ```
2. Now I see two possibilities for an empty error bar to appear:

   1. `formik.errors.email` must be truthy, but not printable (like for example `" "`).
   2. `formik.errors.email` must be truthy, and `formik.touched.email` must be falsy.

   Most probably it's the second issue you're experiencing.

So, if I guessed right, you need to either:

1. Use `ErrorMessage` as it is recommended in the docs. Like so:

   ```js
   <ErrorMessage name="email">
     {msg => <div className="alert alert-danger">{msg}</div>}
   </ErrorMessage>
   ```

   Or like so:

   ```js
   <ErrorMessage
     name="email"
     render={msg => <div className="alert alert-danger">{msg}</div>}
   />
   ```
2. Or get rid of `<ErrorMessage>`, but add a check for the `touched`

   ```js
   {formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email &&
     <div className="alert alert-danger">{formik.errors.email}</div>
   }
   ```

Comment: I took the second solution with `touched`. Thank you.

Comment: It's your right to choose. But I wonder why? Why using `<ErrorMessage>` but not in the way it was suppose to? And why do you choose to waist resources and violate DRY by reimplementing `<ErrorMessage>` and repeating the condition twice, decause doing `{errors.email && touched.email && (<div><ErrorMessage name="email"/></div>)}` is essentially the same as `{errors.email && touched.email && (<div>{errors.email && touched.email && "your string"}</div>)}`

Comment: I'm not sure what you referred to... I chose to implement your `{formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email && <div className="alert alert-danger">{formik.errors.email}</div>}`. It was 3am in the morning and I had to made a choice before the bounties ended. I was not very exhaustive and I quickly tried all the answers and found that the one of Ajeet Shah and your second proposition worked. I accepted your answer but awarded bounty to him (unfortunately we cannot split bounty). Also I accepted your answer in another question... I tried to be "fair" in a limited time... Thanks for your help...

Comment: @x00 You deserved the bounty too but "we couldn't split". I noticed your mention of `touched` after writing my answer otherwise I wouldn't have written my answer. I was in impression that no one is talking about `touched` in this question.

Comment: My mistake. I misread your comment as "**But** I took solution with `touched`". And you've rewarded the bounty to Ajeet's answer that starts with a bolded **touched** :) You're welcome.

Comment: @AjeetShah, not a problem.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to **initialise all input/field values** (may be you have forgotten to initialise value for email?

I have tried to replicate your issue and I was able to see empty pink bar when I don't initialise any field value.

```js
  ...
<Formik
      initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }} // <---- correct - both email and password are initialised
      // initialValues={{ password: "" }} // <--- wrong, email is not initialised. With this, there will be empty pink bar issue
      validate={validate}
      onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
        }, 1000);
      }}
  ...
```

See [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-empty-pink-bar-issue-z8dj8?file=/src/MyForm.js) I created in codesandbox if it is useful

Lastly, I am not sure why do you have the line of code `{error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}`. Just check on that as well.
Good luck.

Comment: if this doesn't work, please update your qn and share more code. thx.

Comment: After opening your exemple, we click inside Email, then we click somewhere else, we will see a pink bar with `Email Required` and an empty pink bar. Do you know how to not show the empty pink bar?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is make use of **`touched`** property of `FormikState`:

```
export interface FormikState<Values> {
    values: Values;
    errors: FormikErrors<Values>;
    touched: FormikTouched<Values>;   // <=== This one
    isSubmitting: boolean;
    isValidating: boolean;
    status?: any;
    submitCount: number;
}
```

Here is how to get access to `touched` state for form:

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' } as IForm}
  validate={(values) => {
    const errors = {} as IForm
    if (!values.email) {
      errors.email = 'Email Required'
    }
    return errors
  }}
  onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    // ... submit handler
  }}
>
  {({ values, errors, touched, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, 
isSubmitting }) => (
                //  above ^ one
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    // ... ...
```

And then use it when showing errors (note the usage of `touched.email` and `touched.password`):

```
<div className="messages-wrapper">
  {errors.email && touched.email && (
    <div className="alert alert-danger">
      <ErrorMessage name="email" />
    </div>
  )}

  {errors.password && touched.password && (
    <div className="alert alert-danger">
      <ErrorMessage name="password" />
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```

To see all of it (Problem + Solution) in action: [Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formil-errors-fvvn6?file=/src/App.tsx)

---

**Snapshot: No empty `div` in DOM inside wrapper:**

[image: no empty dom]

Answer (score 0):

The reason You see the pink bar is because when you have an error with your form submission you render an error message.

Since you use `bootstrap classes` such as `alert alert-danger` on the alert message, the alert is styled as per bootstrap(assuming youare using bootstrap)

According to [bootstrap documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/alerts/):

> Use the `.alert-${link}` utility class to quickly provide matching
>   colored links within any alert.
>
> And accordingly
>
> ```
> alert-success - leaves a green color background
> alert-info - shows a blue color background
> alert-waning- shows a yellow color background
> alert-danger - shows a pink/red color background
> ```

In order for you to remove the pink styling, you can just remove `alert-danger`class from the alert message

```
{error && <div className="alert">{error}</div>}
```

Now this will inherit the styles of `alert` class and if you don't want it, you can just add your custom class and apply styles on it

You code might look like

```
<div className="messages-wrapper">
      {formik.errors.email && <div className="alert">
        <ErrorMessage name="email" />
      </div>
      }
      {formik.errors.password && <div className="alert">
        <ErrorMessage name="password" />
      </div>
      }
      {error && <div className="alert">{error}</div>}
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Without going deeper, I would simply fix by applying css:

```
.alert:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

Otherwise, I would trim value before its check. Eg.

```
{formik.errors.email.trim() &&
```